# What happened to the Lion Turtles?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

It was said in the Legend of Korra that the Lion Turtles would stop protecting humans. But what happened to them? Technically they weren't spirits so they didn't return to the Spirit World like the others.

So really my question is did they just die off or pretend to be islands and is there any information to support this or go against this?

Answers are kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is stated in [Avatar Wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Lion_turtle_%28species%29) that "all but one of these creatures were hunted to extinction."
It looks like this information were available in Nick's website, althought it can't be found anymore.

[image]

I found out this image, but I don't know if this is really from Avatar's website or not

Comment: The wording there makes it sound like this is from *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, which means it may have been retconned by the recent events in *Korra*.

Comment: This is just speculation on my part but Mabey they were hunted for sport a long time ago. Before dragons where hunted to extinction.

Answer (score 1):

They are island currently. In one of the episodes in LOK it was hinted that avatar island might be a baby lion turtle. But then Tenzin said that they were "Hiding too well for us to see" so maybe it is, But where did the original lion turle find a mate? Also in LOK the backstory said that lion turltles were HUGE so the one in ATLA may be a baby too.